# else statement not triggering

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

I have been attempting to create an if else statement that will return a text string based on certain constraints. The first 3 constraints work, but when the event of the final constraint occurs, it triggers the second again. The random number generator occasionally used a 0 value, so I wanted to account for that. I am new to this, and apologize for indenting, etc.

I have been looking around here for a bit and couldn't find anything that seemed to cover this. If I missed it, a hint in the right direction would be appreciated as well.

```
double txtestimateCategory = [mynum computeVolume];
NSLog(@"The volume is %f", txtestimateCategory);
int v = ((txtestimateCategory * 1));
if ((v >= 8000))
{
    NSLog(@"The box is large");
}
else if ((1 <= v < 1000))
{
    NSLog(@"The box is small");
}
else if ((1000 <= v < 8000))
{
    NSLog(@"The box is medium");
}
else
{
      NSLog(@"The box is a lie");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Comparators are binary operators. You have to write:

```
else if (1 <= v && v < 1000)
```

etc.

(Otherwise  you would be evaluating things like `true < 1000`, and `true` converts to `1` implicitly. Not what you meant!)